# Qt сервер стрима аудио

Tags: qt

Добрый день. Есть задача разработать простой сервер для стрима аудио. В браузере слушать с помощью тега audio.  Поэкспериментировал с тегом audio. Если указывать ссылку на wav файл, то все работает. Но я не пойму, как отсылать непрерывный поток аудио с помощью Qt?? Подскажите, в какую сторону копать.Q

Answer (score 1):

Qt не имеет инструментов для стриминга, что называется из коробки, поэтому придётся строить свою собственную реализацию сервера (тот же http или иное, посерьёзнее), используя `QTcpServer`. Соответственно, как только клиент подключится к серверу по указанному адресу и порту в теге `audio`, последний должен начать раздачу данных в формате, приемлемом для клиента. Источником этих данных может быть и файл, и микрофон, да собственно даже другой стриминговый сервер.

Другой вопрос, что реализация такого подсобного хозяйства, так сказать, собственными руками оправдана разве что только с академической целью, поскольку имеется множество уже готовых решений. Например, тот же ffmpeg.